# How to color cells based on a date difference criteria in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need to put the color yellow in all the lines which the difference between the values of column F and A1 is smaller than 7. So, if F4-A1 is <7, line 4 should be yellow, then if F5-A1<7, line 5 should be yellow.. until the end of my rows. If the difference is higher than 7, the line should be blank. I would really appreciate your help

I tried to write the following code:

```
Sub futurospgtos()

Dim i As Integer
    For i = 15 To 1 Step -1
        If IsDate(Cells(i, 6).Value) - Range("A1") < 7 Then
       Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
       Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `If IsDate(Cells(i, 6).Value) - Range("A1") < 7 Then` is problematic because IsDate will return a True or False value, not a number. You can guess why `True - Range("A1") < 7` would cause an error.

I check if there is a date, and if it is, THEN I try to make the substraction. Although I would be careful substracting dates like that.

```
Sub futurospgtos()

Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 15 To 1 Step -1
        If IsDate(Cells(i, 6).Value) And IsDate(Range("A1")) Then
            If Cells(i, 6).Value - Range("A1") < 7 Then
                 Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Else
                 Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        End if
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you have trouble, it will possibly be because of the date format. Let me know in the comments.

Comment: Can you tell me which line causes the error? Maybe we should check if A1 is a Date as well, shouldn't we? I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Also, I put application.screenupdating = False at the start so it doesn't show the changes one by one (although for 15 lines you would not see the difference). I made it go back to True at the end. I believe that's what you wanted.